# In what sense is the S-combinator "substitution"?

Tags: lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

According to the Wikipedia page on SKI-combinator calculus, I is the identity function, K is the constant function, and S is "substitution".  I understand the first two, but I don't see what S has to do with substitution and wikipedia offers no explanation or clarification.

Answer (score 7):

I think the name $S$ arises because of the role that the $S$ combinator plays in the conversion from lambda-terms.  Suppose you have a lambda-term $\lambda a.(P Q)$ and you want to find an equivalent $SKI$-combinator. (The $S$ combinator is not involved except when the term has this form.)  This term  takes its argument   $T$ and *substitutes* it into $P$ and $Q$ in place of the free variable $a$, then applies the result $P[a:=T]$ to the result $Q[a:=T]$.

When we convert to combinatory logic, there are no parameter variables.  So in place of the $\lambda$-abstraction, we need a combinator which performs an analogous *substitution* operation on its arguments. This combinator, which we  call $S$, will take $P$ and $Q$ and an argument $T$ and perform the combinatorial analogue of substitution before applying $P$ to $Q$.  That is, we want $$S P Q T = (P T) (Q T).$$

The other two $SKI$-combinators, $K$ and $I$, do not perform this substitution.  $I$ is used in the trivial case when one is converting the term $\lambda a.a$, and $K$ is used in the case where there is no substitution, when the bound variable $a$ does not appear in the body of the abstraction and so no substitution of the argument for the bound variable is necessary.

(I have been trying to find a citation for this explanation, which I *think* I did not make up myself, but not had any success so far.  If I do find one I will add it.)

[Added 2021: It appears that the letter “S” was originally chosen not for its association with substitution, but because it was the first letter of *schmelzen*, “to fuse”, and that Schönfinkel understood the $S$ combinator not as a substitution operator but as a fusion operator. [See my remarks in the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/889621/25554).]

Answer (score 5):

Read the comments below this answer. It turns out that my reference was wrong.

These are the original combinators as Schönfinkel originally named them:

- I: Identitätsfunktion (identity function)
- C: Konstanzfunktion (constant function)
- S: Verschmelzungsfunktion (amalgamation function)
- T: Vertauschungsfunktion (exchange function; renamed C in Curry's system)
- Z: Zusammensetzungsfunktion (composition function; renamed B in Curry's system)

So... no. I can't think of any reasonable sense in which S means "substitution". I think an edit of Wikipedia is in order.

---

Source: Paul Taylor, [*Practical Foundations of Mathematics*](http://www.paultaylor.eu/%7Ept/prafm/index.html).

---

(This is too long for a comment, but it is directly pertinent, so I am adding it here. —MJD 2017)

I have been reading Schönfinkel 1924 again, and he does not seem to think of $S$ as anything like a substitution operator. One might think of it as a substitution operator if one were mainly interested in converting combinator expressions to functions, but Schönfinkel is mainly concerned with going in the other direction, and for him $S$ is a *fusion* operator, as his name for it suggests. (*Verschmelz* is to fuse or melt together, akin to English “smelt” and “melt”.)  For Schönfinkel, the purpose of $S$ is that if you have an expression with a repeated subexpression, you can first apply $T$ and $Z$ to move the duplicated subexpression into the right position, so that the result has the form $(f x)(g x)$, and then you can “fuse” the two $x$es into one by using the $S$ operator: $(f x)(g x) → Sfgx$.

Schönfinkel does not seem to explain why he decided to name it $S$ instead of $V$.  Note also that he used $C$ for what we now call $K$.

---

(Added this in 2021. — MJD)

I feel a little silly that I didn't think of this before: “Why he decided to name it $S$ instead of $V$” seems clear now.  The name of the function is “Verschmelzungsfunktion”, but the “Ver-” is merely a prefix attached to the main signifier, “schmelz-”.  Two of Schönefinkel's five functions begin with “Ver-“, so abbreviating either as “V” would have been confusing. Instead, it appears that Shönfinkel chose to abbreviate them with “S” for “schmelzen” (melt, fuse) and “T” for “tauschen” (swap, exchange) respectively.

Comment: The root source is §3 of Schönfinkel's original 1924 paper, a translation of which appears in van Heijenoort *From Frege to Gödel: A source book in mathematical logic*, p. 360.  Unfortunately Schönfinkel doesn't explain the abbreviations.  Note that contrary to Taylor's claim, Schönfinkel used $C$, not $K$, to denote the Konstanzfunktion.  [The original German version is available here](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~langeh/test/1924%20-%20Schoenfinkel%20-%20Ueber%20die%20Bausteine%20der%20mathematischen%20Logik.pdf); the names and abbreviations are at the top of page 309.

Comment: $K$ was so-named by Curry; his 1930 thesis *Grundlagen der combinatorische Logik* explains in a footnote “Schönfinkel hat diese bzw. mit $I,C,Z,T,S$ bezeichnet.”

Comment: @MJD You're right. Looks like an edit in PFoM is also in order!

Comment: I have written up [the complete story](https://blog.plover.com/math/combinator-s.html) on my blog.